# How to correctly handle a mix of possible empty strings and objects in JSON deserialization in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am upgrading an old ASP.NET Web API to the latest ASP.NET Core Wen API. I am currently stuck however with empty objects and null values. Our website owner sends empty JSON objects and values as `""` and they don't plan on changing...

For example:

```
{
    "user": "",
    "subscription": {
        "id": 123456789,
        "origin": "",
        "verlenging": true
    },
    "voucher": {
        "name": "",
        "id": 0
    },
    "webLinkId": ""
}
```

Other times they send like this

```
{
    "user": {
        "isDomi": true,
        "isStudent": false,
        "isWeightPromotion": true,
        "startDate": "02/11/2023",
        "weight": 90,
        "firstname": "Test",
        "lastname": "Test",
        "email": "test@test.be",
        "telephone": "123456789",
        "birthday": "",
        "gdpr": true,
        "weblink": "",
        "language": "en",
        "klantId": "",
        "type": "",
        "CommercialContact": false
    },
    "subscription": {
        "id": 123456789,
        "origin": "",
        "verlenging": false
    },
    "voucher": {
        "name": "",
        "id": 0
    },
    "webLinkId": 123456789
}
```

This means my code has to be able to convert empty strings to null or 0 and parse where necessary how should I do this?

I have tried to use attributes and converters but they don't seem to work or I'm doing it wrong could anyone show me how to handle this?

Currently the main error is:

> The JSON value could not be converted to ...

Comment: Are you using System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json to parse the JSON?

Comment: Is your application making the HTTP request and the response has these payloads, or is the JSON the HTTP request sent to your application and handled in a controller?

Comment: i'm using System.Text.Json and the http request is sent to my application and then handled in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with JSON data that has a mix of empty strings and actual nulls or zeros in ASP.NET Core, you can create custom JSON converters that handle the deserialization process to accommodate these mixed types. Here's how you can approach it:

Create Custom Converters:

For nullable value types (like int?, bool?, etc.), you can create a converter that checks if the string is empty and, if so, returns null; otherwise, it tries to parse the value.
For reference types (like string), you can create a converter that treats empty strings as null.
Configure JsonSerializerOptions:

In your Startup.cs or wherever you configure your services, add these converters to the JsonSerializerOptions that are used by the system when deserializing.

```
public class EmptyStringToNullConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String && reader.GetString() == "")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return reader.GetString();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}

public class EmptyStringToZeroConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String && reader.GetString() == "")
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return reader.GetInt32();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteNumberValue(value);
    }
}
```

Add the following to your Program or Startup class, whenever you register your services

```
  builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
  {
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EmptyStringToNullConverter());
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EmptyStringToZeroConverter());
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know about the add jsonoptions part. It's not written in the how to write custom convertsers from Microsoft.